# Maximum meeting limits a user can join via Skype For business ucwa application

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa, skype4java

I need to check whether a user is in the lobby in several meeting at once. I am able to get the required information via EventChannel If I join a user via skype ucwa application. This works for up to 4 meetings for me. Meaning if I join for the same user to 4 different meetings I get events in event channel which belongs to 4 meetings and can find whether another user is in the lobby or not.

But in production environment this number can be reached to more than 100 and also I need to execute these steps in a timely manner. Say once in every 3 minutes I need to check whether users are in lobby or not. But right now if I try to join more than 4 or sometimes 5 meetings I get a 403 error and error code is "**Forbidden**" and the error subcode is "**MaxEventCountReached**".

There is no documentation about this errorcode anywhere. Even after 4 meeting joins If I try to Delete the skype aplication which I use to initially log in and create(**POST**) the application again and try to join meeting ,most of the time I get the error.

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed ?

P.S Client application is written in Java

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join more than 4 meetings at one time by design. I cant really think of a good way to join lots of meetings for monitoring lobby's. This can be handled by the Trusted Application API for meetings in O365. Its not using a user principal which is restricted to the 4 meeting joins. You can join a Trusted Application endpoint to more than 4 meetings but I have not actually tested this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away from staying in these meetings, you can quite quickly join, check and leave. However, see the MaxConferencesPerHour setting in the UCWA Website. By default its 40 an hour. Increasing this number would allow you to join as many conferences as your infastructure can handle.

MaxEventCountReached comes from either joining more than 40 meetings in an hour per sip address, or exceeding 6000 events in a queue per ucwa application, you can clear down this queue by polling the events endpoint.